# How can I display each record individually into a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I use this `while` loop to display events from facebook. I want to add an `href` link in each record that will open a new tab displaying only this event. I have created links for each record but I can't understand how I can make the link to lead to that event.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td rowspan='6' style='width:20em;'>";
        echo "<img src=". $row["COVER_PHOTO"]." width='200px' />";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='width:15em;'>What:</td>";
        echo "<td><b>". $row["NAME"]."</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";  
        //owner
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Who:</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["OWNER"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>What kind:</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["PAGE_CAT"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>When:</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["START_DATE"]." at ". $row["START_TIME"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Where:</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["PLACE"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='view.php?more=". $row["EVENT_ID"]."' target='_blank' <?php echo >Λεπτομέρειες</a>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Description:</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["DESCRIPTION"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: What version of the Facebook SDK are you using?

Comment: Why do you have `<?php echo >` inside the argument to `echo`?

Comment: That version has been deprecated for a while. I highly recommend migrating to v4 if it's at all possible

Comment: I 'll correct the <?php echo>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for this page is just fine. Now to display each individual event in the `view.php` file, you will need to access the data (in your case the event ID, stored in `more` variable) sent via `GET` method in the `view.php` page, as thus:

> view.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['more']))
{
    $more = $_GET['more']; 
}      

?>
```

The value of the `more` variable sent via the URL will now be saved in the `$more` PHP variable. For example, if the page called is `view.php?view=22`, the `$more` variable will have the value of `22`.

You can now use this `$more` variable - which stores the event ID - to fetch whatever other detail you require.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It worked fine. Now i am aware of the existance of GET method! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo "<a href='view.php?more=". $row["EVENT_ID"]."' target='_blank'> Λεπτομέρειες</a>";
```

Comment: I've already done that as you can see. I'm new at this. How view.php will "know" which event has been chosen?